# Why does xcode think I have not completed implementation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

Probably an easy problem to fix but I'm new to this so thank you 
Just trying to understand how to use iAd and put it in

my .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface withadViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
ADBannerView *banner;
BOOL bannerIsVisible;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL bannerIsVisible;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet ADBannerView *banner;
@end
```

my.m

```
@implementation withadViewController;                        **incomplete implementation**
@synthesize banner;
@synthesize bannerIsVisible;

-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner 
{
    if (!self.bannerIsVisible) 
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.0, 50.0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}
```

...continues with rest of basic add banner ad code
Thanks for helping in advance

Comment: Post your header file.

Comment: You've declared your class to implement a certain protocol, but then haven't implemented all of the required methods for that protocol.

Comment: Just posted the header file

Comment: @NicholasHart I'm so new I don't know what that means

Comment: Could you post complete header file? I do not see @end so I assume it continues and there could be an additional methods. As for ADBannerViewDelegate all methods of it are optional, so it should not be an issue. Issue could be in your other methods.

Comment: I just didn't have that in there. There's nothing else after the properties

Comment: Look at the `ADBannerViewDelegate` protocol.  Look at the methods declared in it.  Copy any of them that are not listed as `@optional` into your class's .m file and provide an implementation.  Also go read up on Objective-C protocols.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semicolon (;) from the end of the @implementation line so it is

```
@implementation withadViewController
```

Also make sure you have a matching `@end` for each `@interface` or `@implementation` to close the block.

```
@interface

... your code...

@end
```

and similarly

```
@implementation

... your code ...

@end
```

**Update:**

Remove

```
{
ADBannerView *banner;
BOOL bannerIsVisible;
}
```

because the @property declarations already create instance variables to back the properties. 
Also, make sure you aren't creating another variable named `banner` locally in your code.

The compiler is complaining because you had an instance variable named `banner` and a variable inside `-bannerViewDidLoadAd:` also named `banner`, so inside that method it didn't know which variable you were referring to when you referenced `banner`. So to be safe, change

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
```

to

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)bannerView
```

and reference `bannerView` in the code of that method instead of `banner`. You'll have to do this for other methods that use a local variable named `banner` as well.

Comment: I tried that but now it says local declaration of banner hides instance variable

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the way you declare ADBannerView

```
@interface withadViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
//problem is here .. you might need to add IBOutlet, if you have used interface builder
ADBannerView *banner;
BOOL bannerIsVisible;
}
```

I think it should be like following

```
@interface withadViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
//you forget to add IBOutlet in front of ADBannerView
IBOutlet ADBannerView *banner;
BOOL bannerIsVisible;
}
```

I hope it works... Best of luck

Comment: incomplete implementation pops up when you add a method in .h file and you did not declare in .m file and also when you did not implement required delegate method.

Comment: also you don't need to declare same variable twice... try deleting both variable (ADBannerView *banner;
BOOL bannerIsVisible) inside interface only....

Comment: Looks like it didn't have any effect on the problems. Same problems still exist

Comment: I saw your other post, I saw you have two methods..calulate and clear... are those methods working properly